# JSON parsing incomprehension

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, json

In my application I catch the response from server in json format, something like this:

```
{"hotels":
  {"data":
    [{"id":"id1",
    "country":"counry1",
    "state":"state1",
    "city":"city1",
    }
    {"id":"id2",
     "country":"counry2",
     "state":"state2",
     "city":"city2",
    }]
  }
}
```

If I try to access to element by this code

```
ID = [[[ParsedResponse objectForKey:@"hotels"] objectForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"id"];
```

everything is ok. But if I do

```
NSMutableDictionary *ItemsFromParsedResponse = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
ItemsFromParsedResponse = [ParsedResponse valueForKeyPath:@"hotels.data"];
while (ItemsFromParsedResponse = (NSMutableDictionary*)[ParsedResponseEnumerator nextObject]) {
    ID = [ItemsFromParsedResponse valueForKey:@"id"];
}
```

ID is [null]. And I don't understand, why.
Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're either doing something strange here, or we don't have all your code. I would write your failing piece of code as follows:

```
 itemsFromParsedResponse = [parsedResponse valueForKeyPath:@"hotels.data"];

 for (NSDictionary *jsonFragment in itemsFromParsedResponse) {
     jsonID = [jsonFragment valueForKey:@"id"];
 }
```

I've followed the convention of variable names beginning with a lowercase character (starting with an uppercase character should be reserved for class names), and I'm using fast enumeration, bearing in mind that the information at `hotels.data` is an `NSArray`. I've also renamed `ID` to `jsonID` to avoid confusion with the `id` pointer.